# Is this equation correct? And if so, is this famous?

Tags: real-analysis

> $$\int_1^{\infty}x^n e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{e} \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

**My proof.**<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKsbs.jpg)</sup>

\begin{align*}
&\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{e^{-\alpha}}{\alpha}, \\
&\Rightarrow \qquad \int_{1}^{\infty} (-x)^n e^{-\alpha x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} (-1)^k k! \frac{1}{\alpha^k}(-1)^{n-k}e^{-\alpha} \\
&\Rightarrow \qquad \int_{1}^{\infty} x^n e^{-\alpha x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \frac{e^{-\alpha}}{\alpha^k}.
\end{align*}
$\alpha = 1$とすれば、
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{e} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}.
\end{align*}
が成り立つ。 $\blacksquare$

---

Original images: ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKsbs.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDbEk.jpg))

Comment: Please learn how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It is certainly not famous.

Comment: I proved this equation by chance...

Comment: @StarlightRoad: I won't believe you unless you show that proof.

Comment: Certainly $\Gamma (z) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt$ is a famous function, and yours is just slightly removed.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: @YvesDaoust I added my proof.

Comment: How do you justify the first implication ?

Comment: sorry e^(-αx)→e^(-α)

Comment: How do you justify the first implication ?

Comment: I corrected my mistakes

Comment: How do you justify the first implication ?

Comment: A slightly more general form of this integral is number 3.351.2 (with $u=\mu=1$) on page 310 of _Table of Integrals, Series, and Products_ by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. The indefinite integral (from which yours can be derived) is number 521 on page 379 of the CRC Standard Mathematical Tables, 24th edition.

Answer (score 11):

Is it famous?  probalby not.  Is it known?  Yes.

In:
Gradshteyn and Rhyzik, *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*
formula 3.351.2 is
$$
\int_u^\infty x^n e^{-\mu x} dx = e^{-u \mu} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}\;
\frac{u^k}{\mu^{n-k+1}}
$$
Now if you take $u=\mu=1$ you get your formula.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what it means to be famous, but it is a quite well-known formula in probability theory. Indeed, let $X$ be the sum of $(n+1)$ i.i.d. $\text{Exp}(1)$ random variables. Then

1. $X$ has the PDF $f_X(x) = (x^n e^{-x} / n!) \mathbf{1}(x > 0)$, and so,

   $$ \int_{1}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x = n! \,\mathbf{P}(X > 1). $$
2. $X$ can be realized as the $(n+1)$-th arrival time of the Poisson process $N = (N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ with unit rate, and so,

   \begin{align*}
   \mathbf{P}(X > 1)
   &= \mathbf{P}(\text{$(n+1)$-th arrival has not occurred by time $1$}) \\
   &= \mathbf{P}(\text{there are at most $n$ arrivals by time $1$}) \\
   &= \mathbf{P}(N(1) \leq n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}e^{-1}. \end{align*}

Combining two observations proves the desired identity.

Answer (score 2):

It is true and changing the summation order results in a slightly different expression, which I find easier to prove:

> $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x}dx = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!}$

You can prove it by using induction and integration by parts:

> case n = 0:
>
> $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^0 e^{-x}dx = [-e^{-x}]_1^\infty = 0 + \frac{1}{e} = \frac{1}{e} \frac{0!}{0!}$
>
> step $n \rightarrow n+1$:
>
> $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{n+1} e^{-x}dx = [-x^{n+1}e^{-x}]_1^\infty + (n+1)\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{n} e^{-x}dx = \frac{1}{e} + (n+1)\left(\frac{1}{e}\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!} \right) = \frac{1}{e} \left(1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{(n+1)!}{k!}\right) = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} \frac{(n+1)!}{k!}$